# Check if key is already bound in vimscript / Map key only if not mapped already

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript

I'm wondering if it is possible to check in vimscript if a key (or key combination) is already bound?

I know about the `:map` command which lets me see visually which keys are bound to what actions, but what I am looking for is a way to check it programmatically and perform actions conditionally.

---

My concrete scenario is the following: I like the the possibility to dynamically/manually map `<leader><leader>` to what I need in different cases. (eg. while programming python: run the script. Or compile while programming c++). I usually do it by typing `:nmap <leader><leader> :!make && run program` manually while editing.

Now I want to check in my `.vimrc` if the combination is already bound (by a plugin, or manually) and if not map it to a default action.

In short words: How can I map a key only if it is not already bound?

Comment: I think you are facing a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/288754). Instead of conditionnaly mapping your key, you might prefer reading [`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin) and [`:h 'makeprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27makeprg%27). The idea is to set a different `makeprg` for each filetype you're dealing with and having just a generic mapping which will call `:make`. Otherwise maybe check [`:h :redir`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3aredir) to see how to get the output of `map` into a variable.

Answer (score 8):

You've got:

- [`:h maparg()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#maparg%28%29)
- [`:h mapcheck()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#mapcheck%28%29)

that, respectively permit to:

- get the exact mapping bound to the exact keybinding passed as parameter
- check whether there is any mapping bound to a keybinding starting as the parameter

On the other way around (get which keybinding could be bound to an action), so far I've only found the following

```
function! lh#mapping#who_maps(rhs, mode) abort
  " lh#askvim#execute  =~ split(execute(...), "\n")
  let maps = filter(lh#askvim#execute(a:mode . 'map'), 'v:val =~ a:rhs."$"')
  " Unfortunatelly, knowing exactly what mapping is associated to a
  " keybinding, it's best to use maparg()
  let lhs_list = map(maps, 'split(v:val)[1]')
  let mappings = map(lhs_list, 'maparg(v:val, a:mode, 0, 1)')
  call filter(mappings, 'v:val.rhs == a:rhs')
  return mappings
endfunction
```